# move a placeholder to left in select

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to move my placeholder text to left and drop-down arrow to right, i have values in an array of object. what i need is my placeholder to move left and arrow to right

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="Country" item-right name="Country" placeholder="Select country" required>
          <ion-optionv value={{item.val}} *ngFor="let item of options" >{{item.name}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
</ion-item>
        <button [disabled]=!form.valid ion-button type="submit" value="Submit" block>Submit</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

try this!

```
ion-select{
  width:100%;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  padding-left:0px;
}
```

If it doesn't work, some CSS property must be overriding it. Mark both properties as **!important**

Comment: drop down arrow is not moving to right, placeholder moves

Comment: add this also to the class **max-width: 100% !important;**

Comment: arrow moved but current text in placeholder are not alinged with other placeholder above

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan inspect it with chrome and try to find out the CSS property which is causing this issue. It must be padding or margin, just remove it!

Comment: thanks, i just ajust to my app ion-select {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    height: 41px !important;
}